# remove alphabets from date fromat and save in next column in sql table

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a big table with dateformat which includes 'T' and 'Z' alphabets. I want to remove these two alphabets and save rest of the date in next column. My table (tbl_entso_cdbf) looks like:

```
     Utc          |date|area_in|area_out|  value  | 
---------------------------------------------------
2015-12-05T03:00Z |NULL| 275   |  40    |   0     |
2015-12-05T03:00Z |NULL| 275   |  40    |   0     |
2015-12-05T03:00Z |NULL| 275   |  40    |   0     |
2015-12-05T03:00Z |NULL| 275   |  40    |   0     |
```

I want my table to look like:

```
    Utc           |      date      |area_in|area_out|  value  | 
---------------------------------------------------
2015-12-05T03:00Z |2015-12-05 03:00| 275   |  40    |   0     |
2015-12-05T03:00Z |2015-12-05 03:00| 275   |  40    |   0     |
2015-12-05T03:00Z |2015-12-05 03:00| 275   |  40    |   0     |
2015-12-05T03:00Z |2015-12-05 03:00| 275   |  40    |   0     |
```

The datatypes for column utc is `VARCHAR` and for date column is `DATETIME`.
I have tried available solutions but coudn't work. How can I write a sql query to make changes in my table?

```
1) UPDATE tbl_entso_cdbf
   SET date = CONVERT(datetimeoffset, utc, 113)

2)`select convert(varchar(50), cast(utc as date), 113) from tbl_entso_cdbf`
```

It gives me error like: `MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(10), cast(utc as DATETIME), 113)....`

I appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert time using DATE_FORMAT and then use it to set/update

```
UPDATE `tbl_entso_cdbf` SET `date` = DATE_FORMAT(utc, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i");
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, It works fine. I tried different available methods but couldn't work. This works perfect. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Use the [str_to_date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function which converts a string to a date :)

```
UPDATE `tbl_entso_cdbf` SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE(utc, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%iZ");
```

Comment: Thanks Fancypants ! I tried your solution too. It works absolutely fine.